# Invalid Cell Reference Error while vlookup?

Tags: excel, vlookup

1. Need to look up values under column A of sheet1 and match it with  values under Column A of sheet2.
2. If matches , Return the corresponding value under column B of sheet1 as result .
3. Display the result under column C of sheet 2.

I came up with below vlookup formula and apply it on column C of sheet 2 but it gives error `Invalid Cell Reference Error`

`=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A:A,A:A,Sheet1!B:B,FALSE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the column c of Sheet2 use this vlookup formula.For example in Sheet2, cell c2 if you paste this formula.
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)

The formula will look for the value in cell A2 of Sheet2 in Column A of sheet1 and return the corresponding value in columnB(exact match)of Sheet1 to Cell c2 in sheet2.

Hope this helps!

Comment: you used `Sheet1!A:B` to  look the value in Column A of Sheet2   . Why not `Sheet1!A:A` ?

Comment: That is the table array. The array needs to span the column with the Lookup value AND the column with the match value  @user3198603

Comment: If this, and Tim’s clearly laid out response, do not help you understand you may need to simply watch a quick tutorial on VLOOKUPS on YouTube or something.

Comment: >Why not Sheet1!A:A ? You need the corresponding value of B for the match in A. So, your table array needs to be Sheet1!A:B and NOT Sheet1!A:A.

Comment: @ShankarDuvvuri Thanks . I need to apply this formula to complete column C. One way is I paste this formula to cell c2 first and then extend to all cell of column c2. Is there any other simple way i can apply in one go ?

Comment: >One way is I paste this formula to cell c2 first and then extend to all cell of column c2. This is the easiest way to do it.Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Your `VLOOKUP` syntax looks seriously off to me.  It should be something like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A2:B100,2,FALSE)
```

This assumes that:

- You are entering this formula into cell `B2` on Sheet1
- Your data begins at row 2 of Sheet1 (if not, adjust `A2` to whatever it needs to be)
- Sheet2 has the lookup data also starting in `A2`, and the value is in column `B`

Comment: As Sheet2 has the lookup data also starting in A2, then why not mention just sheet 2 column A i.e. `Sheet2!A:A` instead of `Sheet2!A2:B100` ?

Comment: @user3198603 The second input to `VLOOKUP` needs to be a _table_ containing two or more columns.  The first column is the join column, and the column containing the lookup values needs to come to the right of that.